# Get complete term contents with aggregations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My current aggregations query:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "publication_type": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "publication_type.name"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This will return three separate terms: "annual", "weekly" and "report".

Actually, these are only 2 terms: "weekly report" and "annual report".

How can i get ElasticSearch (using 1.1) to return the full words instead of separate terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default all the fields are analyzed if no explicit mapping is provided.You night have to re-index the entire data with new mapping. The "name" field has to be not_analyzed or you can add a "keyword" tokenizer.

example:

```
"name" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
```

In case you want to retain the name field as analyzed, you can go for multi-field mapping as shown below.

```
"name":{
    "type":"string",
    "fields":{
        "name_raw":{
            "type":"string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
         }
     }
 }
```

now you can use "publication_type.name_raw" in your aggregation query.

Comment: thanks for your clear response, i'll try it out and let you know :)

Comment: It works great! You do not happen to know by any chance how to filter on these multiple words? :)  Just a regular filter query expects a single term